# Graphite browser is blank

Tags: django, graphite

I am new to Graphite real time monitoring tool.

I have installed all the graphite components (webapp, carbon, whisper)
when I start the graphite webapp -

```
PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/whisper ./bin/run-graphite-devel-server.py --libs=`pwd`/webapp/ /opt/graphite/
```

and try to access the browser I get a blank page

Log shows:

```
which: no django-admin in (/opt/grinder/java/jdk1.7.0_67/bin:/home/loadtester/bin:/usr/local/pgsql/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin)
Adding /opt/graphite/webapp/ to your PYTHONPATH
Running Graphite from /opt/graphite/ under django development server

/usr/bin/django-admin.py runserver --pythonpath /opt/graphite/webapp --settings graphite.settings 0.0.0.0:8080
/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/settings.py:234: UserWarning: SECRET_KEY is set to an unsafe default. This should be set in local_settings.py for better security
  warn('SECRET_KEY is set to an unsafe default. This should be set in local_settings.py for better security')
/opt/graphite/webapp/graphite/settings.py:234: UserWarning: SECRET_KEY is set to an unsafe default. This should be set in local_settings.py for better security
  warn('SECRET_KEY is set to an unsafe default. This should be set in local_settings.py for better security')
Validating models...

0 errors found
Django version 1.4.21, using settings 'graphite.settings'
Development server is running at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[

    01/Sep/2015 10:41:01] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 599
    [01/Sep/2015 10:41:02] "GET /browserheader HTTP/1.1" 200 1091
    [01/Sep/2015 10:41:02] "GET /composer? HTTP/1.1" 200 1651
    [01/Sep/2015 10:41:02] "GET /content/js/ext/resources/css/ext-all.css HTTP/1.1" 500 632
    [01/Sep/2015 10:41:02] "GET /content/js/ext/adapter/ext/ext-base.js HTTP/1.1" 500 632
    [01/Sep/2015 10:41:02] "GET /content/js/ext/ext-all.js HTTP/1.1" 500 632
    [01/Sep/2015 10:41:02] "GET /content/js/browser.js HTTP/1.1" 500 632
    [01/Sep/2015 10:41:02] "GET /content/js/composer.js HTTP/1.1" 500 632
    [01/Sep/2015 10:41:02] "GET /content/js/composer_widgets.js HTTP/1.1" 500 632
    [01/Sep/2015 10:41:02] "GET /content/js/completer.js HTTP/1.1" 500 632
    [01/Sep/2015 10:41:02] "GET /content/img/carbon-fiber.png HTTP/1.1" 500 632
```

What am I missing? Looks like the static content is not loaded.

Comment: Came here with this exact same issue. No response even after 7 months! :(

Answer (score 1):

tldr;

The best way to sort out Django static file management is to install whitenoise, and let it manage them for you.

```
# pip install whitenoise
```

More info;

There are several methods to get static files served, recommended by your requirements.  Whitenoise remains the recommendation in most situations, however...

In a development environment, the simple way, as suggested is to set DEBUG=True in local_settings.py, but this is not recommended on a production server, or when you have another process serving the same port, ie apache, etc.

If you have a server running, ie apache, you can get it to serve static files, by creating a folder for static files, and running django-admin to collect the static files into the folder as they would be served by internal processes.

```
# cd /opt/graphite/webapp
# mkdir ../static
# export PYTHONPATH=.
# export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=graphite.settings
# django-admin collectstatic
```

Your configuration file will need to alias /static/ urls to the static folder you created, and grant access. For instance, in apache-graphite.conf, add:

```
Alias /static/ /opt/graphite/static
<Location "/static/">
SetHandler None
Require all granted
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after lots of googling, I changed `DEBUG = True` in `webapp/graphite/local_settings.py` and finally all the resources are loaded!